# Linux Kernel system call implementation with struct parameter

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, system-calls

I just know how to add system calls to kernel of Linux. My system call (like lots of other system calls) takes a pointer to a struct created by me. If I want to add the struct to kernel source how and where should I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a header containing the new `struct` in `include/uapi/linux`.
Avoid namespace pollution by using the appropriate types e.g. `__u16` instead of `unsigned short`/`uint16_t`, `__kernel_time_t` instead of `time_t` ...etc. Check out [`struct mii_ioctl_data`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.14/source/include/uapi/linux/mii.h#L156) for an example.

By adding a `header-y += new_header.h` entry to `include/uapi/linux/Kbuild`, you can then export the header with [`make headers_install`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/headers_install.txt).

By default, it installs the headers in `./usr`. If you want it to install them as system headers, use `make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr` instead. This results in the contents of the `uapi` directory being merged into `/usr/include`. You may then `#include <linux/new_header.h>` in your userspace program.

Comment: How can I include it in user-space programs to test?

Comment: @Alielmo I amended the answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother again. I install headers with no error. But, they are actually not copied to that location. Is it something else I should do?

Comment: @Alielmo My bad. I just revised the answer after testing it locally.